# How to access tileitem inside tilecontrol inside tablelayout?

Tags: vb.net

I want to fill all the tileitmes inside a tilecontrol inside a tablelayout with a specific text.

I assume I should use a `For Each` loop.

How can I do this?

[image: tablelayout, tilecontrol, tileitem]

Comment: You should identify the framework/library which contains these types: **tablelayout**, **tilecontrol**, **tileitem**. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: i want to fill all Tileitem with with any text ex:"hi"..using foreach in vb.net

Comment: If that is what you want to do, you should certainly include it in the question. But you haven't responded to my previous comment -- is this WinForms? WPF? UWP? Android? some kind of JS layout library? some other graphics framework/library? If you don't specify what framework or library you're working with, it's nearly impossible for anyone to give you any answer, let alone an answer that will help you.

Comment: Also, you really should add the steps you've tried to the question: _I tried using a `For Each` on `tilecontrol` like so (including the code) and it didn't compile`_, or _I tried using a `For Each` on `tablelayout` like so (including the code) and it threw an exception`.